# Hibernate 6.2+ with 2nd level cache ignores eager loading

Tags: hibernate, caching, eager-loading

I have project with hibernate 6.2.13.Final and jcache/ehcache for 2nd level cache:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.13.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.13.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- API for 2nd Level Cache -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jcache</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.13.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Implementation for 2nd Level Cache -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
    <version>3.10.8</version>
</dependency>
```

And I have entities with `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` and caching. I know that Eager Loading is an anti-pattern, but the software is complex and it's not possible to change that at the moment.

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
@Audited
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class FooType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Size(max = 36)
    @Column(length = 36)
    @UserInterface(showInForm = false, showInList = false)
    @Comment("Primary key")
    private String id;

    @Version
    @NotNull
    @UserInterface(showInForm = false, showInList = false)
    @Comment("Version column for optimistic locking")
    private int version;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
@Audited
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Foo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Size(max = 36)
    @Column(length = 36)
    @UserInterface(showInForm = false, showInList = false)
    @Comment("Primary key")
    private String id;

    @Version
    @NotNull
    @UserInterface(showInForm = false, showInList = false)
    @Comment("Version column for optimistic locking")
    private int version;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private FooType;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
    
    public FooType getFooType() {
        return fooType;
    }
    
    public void setFooType(FooType fooType) {
        this.fooType = fooType;
    }
}
```

When I query an entry, everything is fine.

```
entityManager.find(Foo.class, id);
```

However, when I query multiple entries, the `FooType` is lazy loaded in the results of `Foo` and is a hibernate proxy object.

```
final TypedQuery<Foo> fooQuery = entityManager.createQuery("FROM Foo f", Foo.class);
final List<Foo> fooList = fooQuery.getResultList();
```

**Hibernate 6.2 and disabled 2nd level cache**

When I deactivate the 2nd level cache, the result is eagerly loaded as expected.

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false" />
```

**Hibernate 6.1 and enabled 2nd level cache**

When I change the Hibernate version to 6.1.7.Final and the 2nd level cache is enabled, the result loads eagerly as expected.

**Hibernate 6.4.0.CR1**

Same issue like 6.2

I'm not sure if this is a bug or an expected change in caching? However, I did not find anything about this in the hibernate 6.2 migration guide. How can I handle this issue, I need the result eager loaded with 2nd level cache enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer in the Hibernate forum:

> Just because you see a proxy object being set for the association doesn’t mean it is lazy loaded. Sometimes Hibernate ORM needs to work with a proxy for other reasons, but will ensure the object becomes initialized as part of a load operation.

[Thread](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/hibernate-6-2-with-2nd-level-cache-ignores-eager-loading/8532) in Hibernate forum with hints for Jackson.